# Python - Please find the error in this combination function?

Tags: python

```
def factorial(n):
    return 1 if (n==1 or n==0) else n * factorial(n - 1)

def perm(n, r):
    nFactorial = factorial(n)
    midValue = n - r
    midFactorial = factorial(midValue)
    answer = nFactorial / midFactorial
    return answer

def comb(n, r):
    perm = perm(n, r)
    rFactorial = factorial(r)
    answer = perm / rFactorial
    return answer
```

The error message says "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'perm' referenced before assignment".

Comment: First line in `def comb`. Your `perm` variable has the same name as your `perm` function.

Comment: `perm = perm(n, r)` you are overriding your function definition of perm.

Comment: You should also be using `//` for integer division rather than `/`. Note also that your functions are inefficient. There is no good reason to compute two large factorials just to cancel many or even most of the factors.